# Outlook: VSTO does not show its initial window

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vsto, outlook-addin

I had developed a VSTO module to Outlook using VB.NET and VS2017-Community.

At the first installation, it asked for an user authorization to install, showing the Product name and the Vendor/Manufacturer data, based on the ClickOnce compilation (I guess).

Everything rans ok...

But now **I uninstalled completely this AddIn** and, when I call the SETUP again (due to a newer  version), the Outlook does not show this window anymore - the Ribbon is updated automatically, my custom ribbon appears, etc.

In other words: my new version is installed into Outlook seemless and runs perfectly; **except for the fact of the VSTO window does not appear anymore** during the Outlook load (which would be like I saw before at the 1.0.0 version of my software).

I would like to see a CLEAN installation, I mean, exactly what a user which had never installed my software would see.

Some data to enlight the problem:

1- I'm using MSI installation and uninstall. Everything runs 100%.

2- The uninstall clears all the registry keys and the application folder.

3- I saw %User%/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0 folder and, also, there are no references to my project.

4- I open REGEDIT and check the following keys. All of them are cleared (no references to my AddIn):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\AddinList
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\1x.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DisabledItems 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\1x.0\Outlook\Resiliency\CrashingAddinList
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\1x.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\1x.0\Outlook\Resiliency\NotificationReminderAddinData
```

(there are no Local_Machine key created here, my Office is 32-bit not running as Admin/Local_Machine).

So, how can I make a clean installation like I saw before?
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

We must clean the references also in:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\1x.0\Outlook\AddInLoadTimes
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO\SolutionMetadata
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO\Security\Inclusion (keys and subkeys)

That's it! :)